# LINQ query for date range?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a bit of a tricky date range function I need.

A Schedule has 2 things... a start date and hours.

End Date can be calculated by doing:

```
   ResolveEndDate(DateTime start, double hours)
   {
       int days = (int)Math.Floor(hours / GetDayHours());

       DateTime dt = start.AddDays(days);
   }
```

This is because a work day has N hours and so forth.

Based on this, I need to find projects which:

- Start before the range and end after
- Start before and end within
- Start within and end within
- Start within and end after

How could I write a LINQ query to do this?

Given something like this:

```
   public static IEnumerable<Project> GetProjectRange(IEnumerable<Project> projects, DateTime start, DateTime end)
       {
           return from p in projects
                  where p.Schedule.DateFrom.Value...
                  select p;
       }
```

The other tricky thing is only month day and year should be considered. Time should not be considered.

1 query that satisfies all 4 conditions.

I have no trouble writing this query, but the way I would do it would be a huge mess. I am hoping there is a better way to do date ranges.

Thanks

Comment: You mean any one of those 4 criteria or a query for each criteria?  Aren't the first and fourth criteria the same?

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake. Also, 1 query that satisfies all 4.

Comment: I'll be honest, this is insane. under those conditions... its EVERY project. No? Do you want them sorted by condition?

Comment: @David Hughes glad someone else pointed it out because I though I was missing something

Comment: No, I am using this for Full Calendar and I only want to show events for that week, but say an event started last week and ends in 3 weeks, you still need to show it... I do not see how this is all projects

Comment: Perhaps post your *huge mess* query and ask how it could be simplified?

Comment: Playing with DateTime ranges ? Look at Noda time : https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/

Comment: I would just like to thank the 2 people that -1'd this question without stating why :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this?

```
return 
    from p in projects
    where 
        (      p.Schedule.DateFrom.Value < start 
            && p.Schedule.DateTo.Value > end
        ) || // 1.
        (      p.Schedule.DateFrom.Value < start 
            && p.Schedule.DateTo.Value > start 
            && p.Schedule.DateTo.Value < end
        ) || // 2.              
        (      p.Schedule.DateFrom.Value > start
            && p.Schedule.DateFrom.Value < end
            && p.Schedule.DateTo.Value > start
            && p.Schedule.DateTo.Value < end
        ) || // 3.        
        (      p.Schedule.DateFrom.Value > start
            && p.Schedule.DateFrom.Value < end
            && p.Schedule.DateTo.Value > end
        )    // 4.
    select p;
```

Comment: This could be reduced to 2 checks since the original 4 cases can be reduced to 2 cases. I think the OP should figure out how if they're curious

Comment: @JRoughan I'm sure it could be simplified logically - I was just providing the 4 clauses that matched his four cases.

Comment: @DStanley For sure. Not knocking your answer at all. Just leaving an exercise for the OP or future readers. Especially since a search on OP would have covered that and this question as well :)